# How to properly handle error from json response

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

First off I am total noob when it comes to writing python so a lot of what I've done thus far has been all learn as I go so with that said:

I have this bit of code here

```py
if buycott_token != '':
    print("Looking up in Buycott")
    url = "https://www.buycott.com/api/v4/products/lookup"
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    data={'barcode':upc,
          'access_token':buycott_token
         }
    try:
        r = requests.get(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)
        j = r.json()
        if r.status_code == 200:
        print("Buycott found it so now we're going to gather some info here and then add it to the system")
        name = j['products'][0]['product_name']
        description = j['products'][0]['product_description']
        #We now have what we need to add it to grocy so lets do that
        #Sometimes buycott returns a success but it never actually does anything so lets just make sure that we have something
        if name != '':
            add_to_system(upc, name, description)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("The connection timed out")
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print ("Too many redirects")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print e
```

98% of the time this works just fine with no issues.  Then I'll scan something with my barcode scanner and I'll get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./barcode_reader.py", line 231, in <module>
    increase_inventory(upc)
  File "./barcode_reader.py", line 34, in increase_inventory
    product_id_lookup(upc)
  File "./barcode_reader.py", line 79, in product_id_lookup
    upc_lookup(upc)
  File "./barcode_reader.py", line 128, in upc_lookup
    name = aj['products'][0]['product_name']
KeyError: 'products'
```

I am certain that it has something to do with how the `json` is being returned. Problem is when this is thrown it kills the script and that is that. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You should print the value of j. The error is telling you it doesn't have a 'products' key at the top level

Comment: You should check if 'products ' is there in the response and then fetch the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error is because of API doesn't give you proper json in response. So I think you can check from your side if key is in API response or not.

```
if 'products' in j:
   name = j['products'][0]['product_name']
   description = j['products'][0]['product_description']
else:
   #Whatever you want when 'product' is not in API response
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `'products'` key in your response JSON. The workaround could be providing a default value if a `'products'` key is not present:

```
default_value = [{'product_name': '', 'product_description': ''}]
j.get('products', default_value)[0]['product_name']
```

or you could simply check whether your response has the products key:

```
if 'products' not in j:
    return 'Product not found'
```

Comment: This would be the problem essentially you are trying to look up something that doesn’t exist in the dictionary